# How to create call screening in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio-studio

With simulring, voice mail picks up and its considered answered. Inside Twilio Studio Flows(or anywhere else inside Twilio), is there a way to have the person answering have to interact to actually accept the call vs just answering the call. I am trying to create a system that rings multiple sales peoples numbers and the first one to answer gets the lead. Voice mails are killing that system.

I've reached out to support with no luck